# Filtering Foundry Fusion Sheets

Tags: palantir-foundry

One of the key features I use in Excel spreadsheets all the time are the sort and filter options. Fusion appears to have a "sort" option if you mark an area as a Table, but I can't find a filter option. Does it exist? How do I access it?

Answer (score 2):

Foundry provides a high volume of data manipulation tools, however even though fusion enables for some tabular manipulation, it is not one of them.

If you have a fusion sheet with a lot of data that you want to filter and manipulate, the recommendation is to sync it to a dataset and use an iterative tool, such as contour, quiver or code workbooks.